# Tiny GUI buttons and text on high resolution monitor

Tags: interface, customization

I recently downloaded blender but when I run the program it is full screen but the nav bars are very small including text and icons. I don't know if its anything to do with the fact my monitor is 4K, I have tried going into resolution settings but it means eeverything else will be too big. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Steps ...

1. Go to User interface
2. Navigate to the System tab
3. Under General Section tune DPI value to fit your need.

No more issue with having a fancy 4k screen ... cheers.

Comment: This is now Display Scale on later versions.