# The fonts on the interface are too small, how can I make them bigger?

Tags: customization

I just downloaded Blender to my Surface Pro 4 tablet, but I cannot read the menu bars, the fonts are too small. How can I make the menu fonts bigger?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44046/15543

Answer (score 3):

Open Blender's User preferences by going to File > User Preferences or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and under the *System* tab the first option under General > DPI should do what you want.

Just increase the DPI to the desired value or to match your display